# How do I delete the contents of a directory if there are spaces in the path?

Tags: linux, bash, find

```
find -name "lastStable" -o -name "lastSuccessful" -exec sh -c "sudo rm -rv {}/*" {} \;
```

As you can see from the above command, I am going through and deleting the contents of the `lastStable` and `lastSuccessful` directories, but leaving those folders behind. However in the `find`, I may end up with paths with spaces such as:

```
/promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable
```

How do I get my find script to handle these paths with spaces within them as well?

Comment: What combinations or variations of `find`/`-exec` have you tried so far?

Comment: none, I haven't been able to find any references online to modify the find exec to handle spaces. I have found information with | xargs but then those have me delete the folder , which I want to keep.

Comment: I have also tried this, but I end up with a cannot remove './lastStable/*': No such file or directory:
find -name "lastStable" -type d | xargs -I{} sudo rm -rv '{}/*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous unix.se question: ["Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely).

The reason the current attempt is failing is that it substitutes the matched file path directly in the argument to `sh -c`; thus if the matched file path is "/promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable", it'd run the equivalent of:

```
sh -c "sudo rm -rv /promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable/*" '/promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable'
```

(the path is included twice because `{}` occurs twice in the arguments to `-exec`.) The shell then performs word splitting on the command it's been given, and runs the equivalent of:

```
sudo rm -rv '/promotions/Production' 'Development' 'Environment/lastStable'/*
```

...which isn't what you wanted at all.

But note that the second occurrence of `{}` in the `-exec` string didn't get word-split, and you can take advantage of this:

```
find -name "lastStable" -o -name "lastSuccessful" -exec sh -c 'sudo rm -rv "$0"/*' {} \;
```

Note the `"$0"` instead of `{}` (so the shell will do the substitution and do it without word-splitting), and the single-quotes around the subcommand (so `$0` doesn't get interpreted before it's passed to the shell). This results in the equivalent of:

```
sh -c 'sudo rm -rv "$0"/*' '/promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable'
```

and then the shell replaces `$0` with the next argument to the shell command, giving:

```
sudo rm -rv "/promotions/Production Development Environment/lastStable"/*
```

which is (as I understand it) exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . -path "*/lastSuccessful/*" -o -path "*/lastStable/*"
```

If that looks likes its going to select all the files/directories inside of the selected paths.

Note it must **never** select a path where "lastStable" or "lastSuccessful" is the *last* element of the directory path.

Then you can change the command to

```
find . -path "*/lastSuccessful/*" -delete -o -path "*/lastStable/*" -delete
```

Which will remove all the subdirectories inside of those paths.

This works because `-path` matches the entire path evaluating it as one string but still honours globbing patterns. The `-delete` will perform the necessary removal mechanism for the file that matches (rmdir or unlink). It should not need special treatment (spaces, etc) because you are not passing the request to the shell (which would normally expand characters like spaces or stars).

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm --` or use `find -inum` or pipe it to a `ls -i` to get the inode #, 
then `rm -i $inode#`

Comment: I can't find anything about rm --. Does that mean I do this: 
find -name "lastStable" -o -name "lastSuccessful" -exec sh -c "sudo rm -- -rv {}/*" {} \; 

Also, for the inode, that looks like it would remove the folder I am performing the search on. Is there a way to do that so that I omit the folder itself, but get all sub folders/files?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to know how I was able to delete folder contents but keep the folder and also handle spaces, here is how I did it:

```
find $PWD -name "lastSuccessful" -o -name "lastStable" -type d -not -empty -print0 | while read -d $'\0' path; do cd "$path"; ls -1 | xargs sudo rm -fvr; done
```

What it does: Finds the full path of the directory I am searching. CDs to that directory and lists the files, then deletes all those files/folders.